# syntax error when trying to use for loop inside dict.update

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

When i run the below code in Python 2.6.6, i get a syntax error at for loop.
However, it runs fine with no issues in Python 2.7.5

```
d.update({i: 'value' for i in d if i[-2:] in ('02', '05')})
```

What modification is needed for it to run in both the versions ?

Comment: I'm telling you, your `for` loop is perfectly fine :)

Comment: Yes, you get a syntax error because that syntax doesn't exist in Python 2.6. See the duplicate for an alternative. `dict.update()` takes the same key-value iterable that `dict()` takes, so `d.update((i, 'value') for i in d if i[-2:] in ('02', '05'))` would work here. In fact, that's *preferable* because that syntax doesn't create a new dictionary just to update another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dict comprehensions were [added in Python2.7 and 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). They do not exist in Python2.6.